# Testing Datamapper models with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sinatra, datamapper

I'm testing a Sinatra application, which is using DataMapper, with RSpec.

The following code:

```
it "should update the item's title" do
  lambda do
    post "/hello/edit", :params => {
      :title => 'goodbye',
      :body  => 'goodbye world'
    }
  end.should change(Snippet, :title).from('hello').to('goodbye')
end
```

Results in this error:

> title should have initially been "hello", but was #<DataMapper::Property::String @model=Snippet @name=:title>

I can of course *hack* this by removing the lambda and only checking if:

```
Snippet.first.title.should == 'goodbye'
```

But that can't be a long term solution since the *.first* Snippet may not be the same in the future.

Can someone show me the right syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it using:

```
it "should update the item's title" do
  snippet = Snippet.first(:title => "hello")
  post "/hello/edit", :params => {
    :title => 'goodbye',
    :body  => 'goodbye world'
  }
  snippet.reload.title.should == 'goodbye'
end
```

Thanks to @Dan Tao whose answer helped me.

Comment: If @Dan answer helped you, why didn't you voted it for the correct answer, and edited you question to bring up the final solution?

Comment: I didn't feel like changing most of his code without his permission. Maybe I should have asked him.

Answer (score 2):

Your spec as written implies that the lambda should actually change the value of the *class* attribute `Snippet.title`; I think what you want is something like this:

```
it "should update the item's title" do
  snippet = Snippet.first(:title => "hello")
  lambda do
    post "/#{snippet.title}/edit", :params => {
      :title => 'goodbye',
      :body  => 'goodbye world'
    }
  end.should change(snippet, :title).from('hello').to('goodbye')
end
```

Right?

Comment: That's logical, thanks. It unfortunately didn't work as `snippet` remains the same variable with the same content. I tried using `snippet.reload`, but it doesn't work inside of the `should change`.