# Rspec doesn't reload changed password attribute - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I am running Rails 3.2.1 and rails-rspec 2.8.1....When I run the test for resetting a user's password, it seems that reloading the user object doesn't load the new password attribute....

Here is the code for my test:

```
 describe "Reset password page" do
    let(:teacher) { FactoryGirl.create(:teacher, :email=>"jane@gmail.com")}
    let(:old_password) { teacher.password }
    before do
      visit reset_password_form_path
      fill_in "Email", with: teacher.email
      click_button "Reset Password"
    end
    it { should have_content('Your new password has been emailed to the address you provided.')}
    specify { Teacher.find_by_email("jane@gmail.com").password.should_not == old_password }
    ## specify { teacher.reload.password.should_not == old_password }  ##THIS FAILS
  end
```

**specify { teacher.reload.password.should_not == old_password }** FAILS but **specify { Teacher.find_by_email("jane@gmail.com").password.should_not == old_password }** PASSES

So this tells me the password is being saved correctly, but not being reloaded...any ideas why?  I am using the Rails 3.2.x "has_secure_password" method for rolling the login/password features.  This means a password_digest is what gets saved to the database, and password is a virtual attribute (I think).

Comment: I had the same issue with `reload`, didn't work inside the `should`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504505/testing-datamapper-models-with-rspec

Comment: in your example, the reload works perfectly, you should just use should_not

Comment: @Samy Dindane, I am confused by your answer at [10504505](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504505/testing-datamapper-models-with-rspec) because isn't my specify{teacher.reload...} line equivalent to snippet.reload.title.should == 'goodbye'??

Comment: Oh sorry man. I was a bit confused when I posted the first comment. Please never mind it. :)

Comment: @apneadiving, sorry, there was a typo - with "should_not" the .reload line fails, that's why I was so puzzled; I've corrected the typo in the original post

Comment: Are you using something like Capybara to drive a browser? If so, you can't use transactional fixtures, which may be turned on in your spec_helper. With transactional fixtures, the code in rspec can't see the database changes made by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just understood: `let` blocks are not loaded till you summon them.

So, because you didn't use `old_password` anywhere before:

```
teacher.reload.password.should_not == old_password
```

Is equivalent to:

```
teacher.reload.password.should_not == teacher.reload.password
```

That's why it just can't fail!

If you want it to ***fail correctly***:

```
old_password #because it's triggered, the value is set and won't be set again
teacher.reload.password.should_not == old_password
```

Edit:

```
describe "Reset password page" do
  let(:teacher) { FactoryGirl.create(:teacher, :email=>"jane@gmail.com")}

  before do
    @old_password = teacher.password
    visit reset_password_form_path
    fill_in "Email", with: teacher.email
    click_button "Reset Password"
  end

  specify { teacher.reload.password.should_not == @old_password }
end
```

Comment: so here is part of the re-written test:   `let(:teacher) { FactoryGirl.create(:teacher, :email=>"jane@gmail.com", :password=>"foobar",:password_confirmation=>"foobar")}
    let(:old_password) { "foobar" }
    before do
      old_password...`    specify{teacher.reload...} still fails even when I call old_password in the before block...At this point, I'm thinking it may be because "password" is a virtual attribute for the teacher model (a password_digest is what actually gets saved to the database) and somehow that's causing it just to reload the FactoryGirl original password.

Comment: Instead of using an instance variable, you can use `let!(:old_password) { ... }` to execute a let immediately instead of lazily (note the exclamation point).

Comment: @RobDavis: nice remark. Still seems weird to use let in this case