# How to test for successful password change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I've put together a basic application with user authentication using `bcrypt-ruby` and `has_secure_password`. The result is essentially a barebones version of the application from the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org). In other words, I have a RESTful user model as well as sign-in and sign-out functionality.

As part of the tests for editing a user's information, I've written a test for changing a password. Whereas changing the password works just fine in the browser, my test below is not passing.

```
subject { page }

describe "successful password change"
  let(:new_password) { "foobaz" }
  before do
    fill_in "Password",               with: new_password
    fill_in "Password Confirmation",  with: new_password
    click_button "Save changes"
  end

  specify { user.reload.password.should == new_password }
end
```

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding some basic detail here.

In short:

1) Why exactly is the code above not working? The change-password functionality works in the browser. Meanwhile, `rspec` continues to reload the old password in the last line above. And then the test fails.

2) What is the better way to test the password change?

**Edit:**

With the initial password set to `foobar`, the error message is:

```
Failure/Error: specify { user.reload.password.should == new_password }
   expected: "foobaz"
        got: "foobar" (using ==)
```

Basically, it looks like the `before` block is not actually saving the new password.

For reference, the related controller action is as follows:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile Updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: I notice that `user` in the spec is a local variable - where have you defined it? Did you use a `let` for that too?

Comment: @lain Yes, just a few lines above I've used `let` to create a user with `FactoryGirl`.

Comment: @veritas1 I've added the error message for reference.

Comment: For anyone interested, there is an answer to a similar and older question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626831/rspec-doesnt-reload-changed-password-attribute-why), which doesn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: And yet another similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647491/app-works-but-in-rspec-test-fails). Maybe this is an rspec bug??

Comment: Have you tried `let!` rather than `let` to make sure that the `new_password` is available in the before block.

Comment: @nmott Yes, I've tried that as well. Still the same result.

Comment: Have you tried putting all the steps into an it block, rather than the before block to see works there? Have you tried save_and_open_page before the click button to see if the password field is being filled in with the expected password?

Comment: @nmott Those are good ideas. Unfortunately, the test still fails with each suggestion. I'm thinking this has to be a funny little quirk in using ```rspec``` with ```has_secure_password```.

Answer (score 9):

For Devise users, use [`#valid_password?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/4.2.0/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method) instead:

```
expect(user.valid_password?('correct_password')).to be(true)
```

Credit: [Ryan Bigg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9342832#comment11820708_9343181)

Comment: If you are rendering after the password change, you will, as in the other examples, need to do ```user.reload``` before calling and testing ```valid_password?```. If you are redirecting, you'll obviously need to test ```assigns[:user]``` or your equivalent in the redirected page.

Answer (score 2):

One not so satisfying solution here is to write a test using the `#authenticate` method provided by `bcrypt-ruby`.

```
specify { user.reload.authenticate(new_password).should be_true }
```

Granted this isn't a proper integration test, but it will get us to green.

Comment: Docs for has_secure_password's authenticate: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

Answer (score 2):

Your answer (using `authenticate`) is the right approach; you should be satisfied with it.    You want to compare the hashed versions of the passwords not the @password (via attr_accessor)  in the model.    Remember that you're saving a hash and not the actual password.

Your `user` in your test is an copy of that user in memory.  When you run the tests the update method loads a different copy of that user in memory and updates its password hash which is saved to the db.    Your copy is unchanged; which is why you thought to reload to get the updated data from the database.

The password field isn't stored in the db, it's stored as a hash instead, so the new hash gets reloaded from the db, but you were comparing the ephemeral state of @password in your `user` instance instead of the the encrypted_password.